# MYSQL selecting multiple rows of same type

Tags: php, mysql

From this MYSQL table which has several hundred cities divided into different sets, I need a page to display a clickable link pertaining to each set (i.e. set 1, set 2 etc.) in a list and when one is clicked on, to take the user to another page where all of the cities that belong to that particular set are displayed.

```
id  __ set __ city
 1  __  1  __ Detroit
 2  __  1  __ Montreal
 3  __  2  __ Paris
 4  __  2  __ Rome
```

I've tried:

```
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `cities`");
        while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
          $set = $result['set'];
```

creating a link on each set:

```
      <a href="pages.php?id=<?php echo $set; ?>"> <?php echo $set ?> </a>
```

and on pages.php:

```
        if(isset($_GET['id'])){

        $page_id = $_GET['id'];

        $select_query = "SELECT * from `cities` WHERE `city` = '$page_id'"; 

        $query = mysql_query($select_query);

        while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
```

But it obviously prints out the same "set" link many times - whereas I need each $set just once in the list. I'm sure it can't be that hard to do if you know what you're doing, and this may even be a bad way of going about it but it's now been many hours and I'm at a loss of how to make it work.

Comment: yes you should use 'select distinct set from cities' to get only one set. But then you miss a good description. Normally, i would create another table 'sets' with a description for each set...(and then your can use select * from sets). This is basic database normalization. BTW 'set' is not really a ideal name for a column.

Comment: I did wonder whether it would end up being better to create a separate table.

Comment: yes thats the better way. 2 tables. 1:N (1 set : many cities), or if a city can be in more then one set,then N:M (3 tables).

Comment: shouldn't it be `set = '$page_id'` instead of `city = '$page_id'`?

Comment: Yes, it should be set = …  In the end I was able to make it work with 2 separate tables and the solution was actually quite straightforward. Much appreciated.